# ROS ImportError: No module named asyncio

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-asyncio, ros, catkin

Image of the error

[image: Image of the error]

I have recently installed ROS(Melodic) in Windows. But using any catkin_tools commands shows the following error: **ImportError: No module named asyncio**. I am using Python 2.7. I have searched about it and it seems like a Python 3.5+ has this asyncio in its library. But the standard installation (given on the ROS website ) downloads choclatey and python27amd64. How can I sort this issue?

Answer (score 2):

As I see in [asyncio github](https://github.com/python/asyncio/tree/master) asyncio supports only Python3:

> asyncio requires Python 3.3 or later! The asyncio module is part of the Python standard library since Python 3.4.

So you will not be able to use it in python2.7

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. As specified, after I finished installing ROS(melodic) in Windows the command python --version tells me that the version of Python is 2.7. I tried to upgrade it using the choco upgrade python command but still the python --version command says that its still Python 2.7. Hence the version of python is not under my control. I have just followed the installation procedure given on  ros.org.

Comment: Ah the problem is that Python2 cannot be upgraded to Python3. They are completely different programs. Actually Python2 is legacy and will not be supported - in ROS2 Python3 is required. Maybe some replacement of asyncio?

Comment: No can't do that. As I said, the installation procedure downloads files named Python 2.7amd64. I am not the one who chooses it and the asyncio library is used in the catkin_tools src files.